# How to make line to find critical temperature of a superconductor

Tags: python, physics

I am trying to determine the critical temperatures of my superconducting samples.
Below is what my resistivity measurements look like.
[Resistivity graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpQnA.png)

I need to make two fitted lines that cross. On above the Tc and the other at the transition temperature (where the graph drops to zero resistivity). An example of this is the picture below.
[Cross fitted lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Now.jpg)

Here is what I have

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file= pd.read_excel('s400.xlsx',skiprows=31) #data is after the first 31 rows.
#Identify the x and y axis of data
x= np.array(file['Temperature (K)'])
y= np.array(file['Bridge 3 Resistivity (Ohm-m)'])
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.scatter(x,y,marker=".")
plt.title("Resistivity vs Temperature")

#need to make two lines that cross in order to find Tc.

plt.show()
```

I tried making a fitted line and I can only figure out a way to make a fitted line for the entire graph.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: i believe you might have to take a average for the values to make the tangent I guess. In this particular example possibly you can identify the set of points using which the changes in resistivity is maximum for line 1 in the fitted graph and the 2nd line could be on the upper bound for which the change is linear and you can exclude the initial points if that's not required (for the fitted graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach to the OP's fitting method and the implementation of that given by Hoodlum would be to look at the gradient.

I'd recommend first fitting the data with the [LOESS algorithm](https://pypi.org/project/loess/) (requires pip install), and then using `np.gradient` for finding the gradient. The first step is important so that we can resample the data at whatever new `xnew` points we like, in particular ensuring they are evenly spaced. This can also help smooth the data.

An improvement to just looking at the max position of the gradient would be to fit a Gaussian/Lorentzian peak shape.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 20
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12,8)

# Function from Hoodlum's answer
def create_synthetic_data(r0, dr, tc, noise=2e-8):
    '''create some fake data, bc OP did not provide any'''
    t = np.linspace(50, 300, 250)
    r = np.maximum(r0 + dr*t - np.exp(-(t-tc)), 0) + \
        np.random.normal(0, noise, t.shape)
    return t, r

t,r = create_synthetic_data(r0=0., dr=1e-8, tc=75.)

from loess.loess_1d import loess_1d
xnew = np.linspace(t[0], t[-1], 1000)
x, y, _ = loess_1d(t,r,degree=0,frac=0.02,xnew=xnew)
assert np.all(xnew == x)

grad = np.gradient(y)
xmax = x[np.where(grad==grad.max())][0]
print(f'Superconducting temperature dervied from max gradient is {xmax:.2f} K')
plt.axvline(xmax, color='r', linestyle='--', label='Critical $T_C$')
plt.plot(t,r, '.', label='Raw data')
plt.plot(x, y, label='LOESS fit')
plt.gca().set(xlabel='Temperature / K', ylabel='Resistivity')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.axvline(xmax, color='r', linestyle='--', label='Critical $T_C$')
plt.plot(x, grad, label='Gradient')
plt.gca().set(xlabel='Temperature / K', ylabel='$\\frac{d\\rho}{dT}$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```bash
Superconducting temperature dervied from max gradient is 89.79 K
```

[image: data fit]
[image: gradient]

Comment: Thank you! This is another way that we can find the Tc according to the literature I reference in on of the visuals above. I've applied this to my data and they turned out great. I do have another sample that gives me two peaks on the gradient graph. If I wanted to determine that peak how would I go about that?

Comment: for multiple peaks, have a look at [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how clean your data is, you could try using a progressive least-squares fit to find the different regions. It's hard to tell without more information about your data (and I'm not a physicist, so my knowledge on the subject of superconductors is pretty limited).

Below example illustrates a possible implementation using a somewhat naive approach (it's slow, but it gets there). It will also require a bit of manual fiddling with parameters to get it exactly as you need it.

After that, finding the Tc from the output is simply a question of solving for the intersection of the regression lines.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def create_synthetic_data(r0, dr, tc, noise=2e-8):
    '''create some fake data, bc OP did not provide any'''
    t = np.linspace(50, 300, 250)
    r = np.maximum(r0 + dr*t - np.exp(-(t-tc)), 0) + \
        np.random.normal(0, noise, t.shape)
    return t, r


def linear_least_squares(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray):
    '''return B such that (B @ x - y).T @ (B @ x - y) is minimized'''
    return np.linalg.pinv(x @ x.T) @ x @ y


def average_square_error(y_predict: np.ndarray, y_true: np.ndarray):
    '''find the average square error per point'''
    delta_y = y_predict - y_true
    error_square = delta_y @ delta_y.T
    return error_square / len(y_true)


def progressive_linear_fit(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, nb_initial_pts: int = 10, error_threshold_factor: float = 20.):
    '''
    returns a numpy array containing the linear fit parameters and the index of 
    the last point which does fit within the error threshold. 
    Starts at the first index of the arrays. 
    '''

    # prepare matrices/vectors for linear least squares
    X = np.vstack((x, np.ones_like(x)))
    B_PREV = np.zeros((1, 2))
    i = 0

    for i in range(nb_initial_pts+1, len(y)):
        # fit all currently accepted points to a least squares line
        xx = X[:, :i]
        yy = y[:i]
        B = linear_least_squares(xx, yy)

        # check qulity of fit on the newest point
        yy_predict = B @ xx
        newest_square_error = (yy_predict[-1] - yy[-1])**2

        # if the quality is bad, assume that we have hit the drop-off
        if newest_square_error > error_threshold_factor*average_square_error(yy_predict, yy):
            break

        # otherwise, the found parameters are ok -> save them for later
        B_PREV = B

    return B_PREV, i-1


def reverse_progressive_linear_fit(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, nb_initial_pts: int = 10, error_threshold_factor: float = 20.):
    '''
    returns a numpy array containing the linear fit parameters and the index of 
    the first point which does not fit within the error threshold. 
    Starts at the last index of the arrays. 
    '''
    b, i = progressive_linear_fit(
        np.flip(x),
        np.flip(y),
        nb_initial_pts,
        error_threshold_factor
    )
    return b, len(x)-i


# create the fake data for the example
t, r = create_synthetic_data(r0=0., dr=1e-8, tc=75.)

# 1) find the low-temperature linear region.
b_lo, i_lo = progressive_linear_fit(t, r, error_threshold_factor=10)
t_lo = t[:i_lo]
r_lo = b_lo[0]*t_lo + b_lo[1]  # we expect b ~= [0, 0], but whatever


# 2) find the high-temperature linear region.
b_hi, i_hi = reverse_progressive_linear_fit(t, r, error_threshold_factor=10)
t_hi = t[i_hi:]
r_hi = b_hi[0]*t_hi + b_hi[1]

# 3) whatever is in-between is the fall-off/cliff region
t_mid = t[i_lo-1:i_hi]
b_mid = linear_least_squares(
    np.vstack((t_mid, np.ones_like(t_mid))), r[i_lo-1:i_hi])
r_mid = b_mid[0]*t_mid + b_mid[1]

# 4) find Tc
tc = - (b_mid[1] - b_hi[1])/(b_mid[0] - b_hi[0])
print(f'Superconducting temperature dervied from progressive linear fit is {tc:.2f} K')

# 5) plot
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(t, r, marker=".", label="raw data")
plt.plot(t_lo, r_lo, "c--", label="supercond. regime")
plt.plot(t_mid, r_mid, "g--", label="transition regime")
plt.plot(t_hi, r_hi, "r--", label="resistive regime")
plt.axvline(tc, color='c', linestyle=':', label=f"$T_c$ = {tc:.1f} K")
plt.title("Resistivity vs Temperature")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output :

```
Superconducting temperature dervied from progressive linear fit is 91.31 K
```

[image: output illustration]

#### NOTE :

The `create_synthetic_data` function has an error in it (a pair of brackets is missing), however, I'm leaving it as-is in the example above, since it was re-used for the accepted answer. It should properly be :

```py
def create_synthetic_data(r0, dr, tc, noise=2e-8):
    t = np.linspace(50, 300, 250)
    r = np.maximum(r0 + dr*(t - np.exp(-(t-tc))), 0) + \ 
        np.random.normal(0, noise, t.shape)
    return t, r
```

Comment: How could you determine the point where the mid and hi cross? Also, I like the reverse progressive linear fit as it may come in handy when determining the pseudogap, but I come to a similar issue of determining the point where the data varies from the fit. Is there any advice you can give?

Comment: In the above example, you can just solve the equation using the B matrices for the two lines to find the intersection. I'll update the answer. 
However, if all you're looking for is Tc you're probably better off using the LOESS algo + gradient, as proposed by Joe Idden. It seems less fiddly?